# Disable 'Bidirectional communication' for a printer?

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-3.0, printers, get-wmiobject

How do you disable 'Bidirectional communication' using powershell?

I can see `EnableBIDI` when running:

```
get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | fl *
```

But when I try this, it says the property was not found?

```
Set-PrinterProperty -PrinterName "Some Printer" -PropertyName "EnableBIDI" -Value $False
```

Comment: I've come across this issue with HP JetDirect before, the code isn't pure PowerShell as it's using printui.dll to make the change, but may well help you: `Invoke-Expression -command "rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n 'MyPrinterName' attributes -EnableBidi"`

Comment: The EnableBIDI property is Read/Write so you should be able to set it with the WMI object.

Comment: @JamesC. how do you specify the value when using attributes -EnableBidi

Comment: Also, Set-PrinterProperty only sets certain properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printerproperty?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing properties from two different WMI classes.  [`Set-PrinterProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printerproperty) manipulates instances of the undocumented `MSFT_PrinterProperty` class from the `root/standardcimv2` namespace, which has different properties than the [`Win32_Printer` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer) in your previous command.

Instead, manipulate the desired instance of the `Win32_Printer` class since that has the property you want, then call [`Put()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.put) to commit the change.  This works for me when run with elevation:

```bsh
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_Printer' -Filter 'Name = ''My Printer Name'''
$printer.EnableBIDI = $false
$printer.Put()
```

Using the newer [`CimCmdlets` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/) you can make that change in similar fashion using the [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/Get-CimInstance) and [`Set-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/Set-CimInstance) cmdlets...

```bsh
$printer = Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Printer' -Filter 'Name = ''My Printer Name'''
$printer.EnableBIDI = $false
Set-CimInstance -InputObject $printer
```

...or simplify it to a single pipeline...

```bsh
Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Printer' -Filter 'Name = ''My Printer Name''' `
    | Set-CimInstance -Property @{ EnableBIDI = $false }
```

...or even simplify it to a single cmdlet invocation...

```bsh
Set-CimInstance -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = ''My Printer Name''' -Property @{ EnableBIDI = $false }
```